# iOS In-App credit card entry for monthly service

Tags: ios, credit-card

I'm working on a mobile app for our service. We are essentially digital assistants (real people) providing a service for a monthly fee. In our sign up process we require a credit card for initial sign up then charge a monthly fee after the trial. Theres no additional purchases in app, just the sign up and charging the monthly service fee.

How does this play into Apple's terms? Can we accept a credit card on sign up within the app or do we need to do that through a web sign up flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within the app with no problems. Since you aren't using in-app purchases and you are not selling digital goods they don't have a problem. I work with an app where we sell prints and we collect credit card info with no problem.